# Database manipulation of biometric data in ANSI 378 or ISO 19794-2 format

Tags: sql, database, biometrics, iso-19794

How would I go about performing queries on `ISO 19794-2` and `ANSI 378` data types in a database? I assume I wouldn't be able to use a language such as SQL?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I came across [MySQL Database for Storage of Fingerprint Data](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221057401_MySQL_Database_for_Storage_of_Fingerprint_Data) but it doesn't really say anything useful.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am honestly in a design phase of this project, and am just trying to identify how best to store said data. The queries I need to perform are just basic - record retrieval and matching, adding, deleting